# Unable to run soap webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot, soap

I am getting the below error at the console when try to run a Soap Spring boot web application-

Usage: RealmBase [-a ] [-e ] [-i ] [-s ] [-k ] [-h ]

I am using TOMCAT to run the application.

Will you please tell me how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the command you are using to run the application ? The error you have metioned here looks like help guide for correctly using RealmBase command, if that's what you are running.

Comment: I am using eclipse. Right click on project->run-> run as java application. the the above error is coming.